# Why terminal in Ubuntu 16 cannot find go version even after setting up path?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, golang

I followed the below steps to set up a workspace for go in ubuntu 16.

1.Downloaded go 1.14 version for linux from https://golang.org/

2.Extracted it in the /usr/local using the command-

`sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

3.Added path in the .profile by adding the line

`PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin"`

4.Sourced this in the session with command -

`source ~/.profile`

5.Checked go version

But the terminal returns the error

The program 'go' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install golang-go

Can anyone please explain where I am going wrong with this ?

Comment: Sorry, both of those things were written by mistake. I'm editing the question.

Comment: Now what is the output of `echo "$PATH"`? What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/go/bin/go`?

Comment: echo $PATH prints /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
and 
ls -l /usr/local/go/bin/go prints 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15307838 Apr  9 00:47 /usr/local/go/bin/go

Comment: Please put this information in the body of the question.